# Unscoped delegation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates, scope, destroyed-at

```
class DonatedItem
    belongs_to :donation_item

    delegate :name, to: :donation_item, prefix: true
end
```

I'm using the destroyed_at gem for DonationItem and I'm running into an error when I call donated_item.donation_item_name on a destroyed DonationItem.

What's a good way to make an unscoped delegate call to a destroyed DonationItem?

Comment: please check out this link i hope it will help you. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the [unscoped_associations](https://github.com/markets/unscoped_associations) gem and updated my DonatedItem model.

```
class DonatedItem
    belongs_to: :donation_item, unscoped: true

    delegate :name, to: :donation_item, prefix: true
end
```